# Convert float to array of bytes in PHP

Tags: php, floating-point, pack, unpack

I need to convert a float value into 4 bytes.

In javascript I usually do it with this code:

```
  var farr = new Float32Array(1);
  farr[0] = 26.75;
  var barr = new Int8Array(farr.buffer);
  console.log(barr[0]+","+barr[1]+","+barr[2]+","+barr[3]); 
  //26.75 => 0,0,-42,65
  //26.85 => -51,-52,-42,65
```

I want to do it in php instead of javascript. I it possible?

Comment: And here is vice versa [enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56786533/how-to-convert-byte-array-to-float-in-php)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try to use **[pack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pack.php)** and **[unpack](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unpack.php)** function:

```
$f = 26.75;
$ar = unpack("c*", pack("f", $f));

print_r($ar);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
  [1] => 0
  [2] => 0
  [3] => -42
  [4] => 65
)
```

you can find a snippet [here](http://ideone.com/EHuKDG)

Comment: Thanks but I don't get the same values with this code as I got with javascript. It you try my 2 examples, values now are differents: 26.85 gives 205 204 222 65

Comment: @Biribu 205 - 256 = 51, same for other numbers, you should subtract the numbers by 256 if they are larger then 128 to compensate for php not giving the number signed (or javascript giving the number unsigned)

Comment: Perfect. Thanks both.

Comment: @Biribu, just use signed char 'c': `unpack("c*", pack("f", $f));`

Comment: For a ModBus float representation You have to use 'v*':`unpack("v*", pack("f", $f));` This results in a two register little endianed uint16 "float"